# Headless UI Tailwind Menu display issue

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui, tailwind-3

I am using Tailwind with Headless UI for my react project. I am having a display issue for Headless UI Menu as shown i the below images -

Correct display -

[image]

Problematic display -

[image]

The menu is open but not displayed outside of the parent. please help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the menu is being displayed inside an element with `overflow: hidden` applied. Consider removing the `overflow: hidden` from the parent element, or move the menu outside the `overflow: hidden` element by using a [portal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal).

Comment: Thanks @Wongjn for your help, I will try this solution. But for now I was able to solve th eissue by changing Menu position from absolute to fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `overflow: visible` to the parent (seems to be a `<table>` element in your case) and that popup will work as expected